# Orbital tether snap like a rubber band?

Tags: science-based, space-constructs, space-elevators

Let’s say a few centuries in the future, we have captured an asteroid into orbit and built a space station out of its material. The station is a ring that encircles the equator in Low Earth Orbit, tethered by multiple cables and moves with the planet at orbital speed.

The first parts of the station were built several centuries before the last ones, and is in constant refit to update older tech with newer advancements. The tethers are made out of a strong material like graphene or nanothreads, and are large enough to allow a space elevator to travel through.

Let’s say there is a catastrophe in one of the older sections, one of the old tethers sheers away from the station with great force. What would happen to the cable as it fell to Earth? Is it possible for it to snap to the earth like a rubber band? Would it need to be made of a different material for it to do this, or is it a physical impossibility? How extensive would the damage on earth be, and how far away could the effects be felt? And what effect would the catastrophe have on the station itself?

Alternatively, would there be a major difference if the tether were instead to break in the middle? my understanding is the top half would float along with the Coriolis force, but could the bottom half snap to the ground or would it just fall over?

I’ve read Blaise Gassend’s thoughts on space elevators, but his examples seem to be for a tether that extends into GEO, well past this particular station. Would the mechanics of his simulated tether breaks be relatively the same for a much shorter tether?

Comment: In Low Earth Orbit, station has to move considerably faster than the surface below. If tethering, it should be tethered to something _above_ it.

Comment: If connected with enough tethers, couldn't the station be slowed to orbital speed?

Comment: A station like this needs to be in geosynchronous orbit. That way its tethers to the ground are practical. If it is closer to Earth than geosynchronous orbit, there are only two possibilities. (a) It completes an orbit in less time than earth rotates, so its tethers to the ground snap or (b) it is not moving fast enough to stay in orbit, and falls out of the sky onto the Earth.

Comment: This means the station is not really orbiting. The antipode tethers are actually bearing the weight of the station. The station itself must be extremely rigid to prevent collapse.

Comment: I got the impression from Isaac Arthur's video on Orbital Infrastructure that a ring could be built lower than GEO and could move with the planet at orbital speed. Is there a trick to getting it to work as described above?
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HkU85zKxK-s

Comment: Orbital speed is directly linked to the radius of the orbit. Orbital speed on a low Earth orbit is considerably higher than the rotation of the Earth below it. For example, the International Space Station goes fully around the world in one hour and a half. A ring anchored to the Earth at low-ish altitude will not rotate fast enough to be in orbit. Unless the ring is somehow made to be incredibly strong it *will* break and the pieces *will* fall down.

Comment: You could possibly have a "rail" along the entire equator that housed the ground-tether bases, allowing the tethers to slide along so the station could rotate faster than the earth to maintain orbital speed. Of course, it'd create friction which in turn would gradually slow the ring down, unless it has ways to increase it's speed. Simply, tethers would likely work better for a ring that's high enough that its inertia is greater than the gravitational pull on it, and the tethers pull it along. Regarding rubber band snapping, even rocks can be somewhat "elastic" (see earthquakes).

Comment: @carsonogen089 I didn't notice anything in the video about "orbital ring". Can you point to a particular time?

Comment: @Alexander I forgot he had an entirely separate video just on orbital rings. Here's the correct link:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LMbI6sk-62E

Comment: @carsonogen089 Ok, I watched it. Very interesting, I never thought about a ring like that. The trick to get it to work, I think, is to make 40,000+ km magnetically levitated cable to move at the speed of 8 km/s for very long periods of time without failing. If this cable snaps, the entire ring is doomed.

Comment: @Alexander The cable is a simplification of the concept. Tidal effects make the cable impractical. You would want to use either a stream of projectiles or particles. For that matter, you want at least four streams so you can cancel out procession. Probably even more than that for redundancy. Check [this](https://jenda.hrach.eu/f2/Low%20cost%20design%20of%20an%20orbital%20ring%20-%202017-1.pdf) for more details on orbital rings.

Comment: @TheDyingOfLight thank you for the link, this is also interesting, though has its own challenges. For Isaac Arthur's ring, I don't think tidal forces would be a showstopper if the ring is non-rigid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cable close to the Earth would fall to Earth possibly creating much damage. Higher sections of the cable would be traveling so fast when they hit the atmosphere that they would burn up. Assuming that only the top station in geostationary orbit is truly in orbit and the rest is in a state of tension, once set free sections further out from the station (counter balance object) would be flung out to a higher orbit and those below would eventually fall to Earth and mostly burn up.

Comment: I think lower cable would burn up too - it is even faster moving than upper.  If this stuff is carbon that would definitely burn up on re-entry.

Comment: Well the cable is stationary with respect to the Earth all the way up so the first few miles is just going to flop onto the ground like a failed indian rope trick, but the higher portions will start coiling and flapping about as they come down and at some height the heating cause it to burn.

Answer (score 0):

The loose tether would burn in the atmosphere. The rest of the station, still holding 99.9999% of the original mass after snapping, would have a tiny-teeny change in its orbit. Maybe some rotational stabilization would be needed, standard issue of anything sitting in orbit.